# Google Calendar, shortcut to get you to the current day while scrolling

Tags: google-calendar, accessibility, user-interface, date-and-time, menu

I wonder whether there is a shortcut (or, alternatively, any quick way) to get you back to the current day (the one we're in in the month we're in in the year we're in) on Google Calendar.

The quickest way I can think of is clicking on the square in the middle of the bottom part of the screen and flicking to where the date widget is on the desktop (if you clicked on it to open Google Calendar it will be the current page), memorizing the date, and returning to Google calendar, scrolling to the given date, while keeping it in mind.

I wonder whether there's a quicker way.

I thought, maybe, from the application menu there could be an entry for current date you could click on, but I couldn't find it (so maybe there is a more efficient way).

Perhaps the best option is just minimizing the app and clicking back on the date on the desktop. Is this the best way to do it?

Thank you for your help.

Thank you for your answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Calendar Help - View your day, week, or month](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110849?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid),

> #### Go to a specific day
>
> [...]
>
> **Get back to today:** At the top right corner, tap Jump to today [image: Event].